# UK standard visitor visa for a Japanese national

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I am a Sri Lankan national currently doing my MBA and my fiancé, who's a Japanese national, intends to visit me for a 3-month period from mid-March. She's currently employed. However, she's currently serving her resignation and intends to take the mentioned period off before commencing her next assignment. Currently we are producing the following documents.

- Her current employment contract (which is set to expire in June).
- Bank statements and balance sheets for the last 3-6 months.
- Sponsorship letter from me providing her with accommodation (as a friend).
- My bank statements and a copy of my passport and residence card.
- Her proof of residence in Japan.

My question here is, are those documents sufficient to get the clearance and approximately how much of funding needs to be presented?

P.S. - Japanese nationals do not require to apply for a visa as they are eligible for automatically for a visit of up to 6 months, but she would like to avoid any hassle at the immigration hence the application.

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: There won't be any hassles. As a Japanese citizen, she's entitled to a 6-month stay, as you mentioned. While visitors from some countries may be considered de facto suspects, there's a reason Japanese travellers are not. She will be fine flying, especially if she has a return ticket.

Comment: I agree with @dda, the hassle is applying for the visa when you don't have to. She might want to bring the bank statement and a letter explaining that she will stay with you, in case she is the rare traveler from an exempt country who gets asked anything beyond "Purpose of trip" at all.

Comment: What do you mean for "hassle at the immigration" ? As far I know, having a visa cause more hassle (check purpose etc.)

Comment: I see. I am not sure of the procedure since I was required to get the visa granted before each visit to UK. She was a bit worried that she would be retained at the immigration to conduct a thorough check on her documentation hence the preference towards an application. However, I'll take it that the consensus are against it.

Comment: @DViperJ Tell her not to shoot herself in the foot by applying for a visa.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in her applying for a visa - only if she's had major immigration-related issues in the UK in the past. Otherwise she might in fact make things more difficult for her.

Tell her she has nothing to be worried about. If she wants to be extra safe, she can bring her return flight confirmation and letter of invitation from you. That's it.